# ASUS WS C621E won't recognize U.2 SSD Intel P4510

Tags: ssd, bios, uefi, nvme, handwriting-recognition

### Hi everybody,

my problem is that my Intel SSD does not get recognized by my Asus Mainboard.

**BIOS>Advanced>Intel(R) Virtual RAID on CPU>All Intel VMD Controllers** says "No disks connected to the system"

Anyhow, **BIOS>Advanced>Intel(R) Virtual RAID on CPU>Upgrade** key says "Premium"

Does anyone has an idea what the reason could be?

---

#### Hardware

I've reduced the components. So for debugging purposes I've attached only a single CPU, RAM DIMM and SSD.

Mainboard:
[WS C621E SAGE
BMC](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/Socket3647/WS_C621E_SAGE/Manual/E15242_WS_C621E_SAGE_UM_V5_WEB.pdf?_ga=2.15146230.117617998.1551772007-136971065.1542829562) (it's already the 2nd one as I've returned the first one because the Asus support thought it was broken)

CPU:
[Intel® Xeon® Silver 4114 Processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/123550/intel-xeon-silver-4114-processor-13-75m-cache-2-20-ghz.html)

RAM:
Samsung DDR4 32 GB DIMM (is listed on the compatibility list of the mainboard and works)

U.2 Cables: [Delock Cable SFF-8643 male > U.2 SFF-8639 female + SATA power connector 50 cm](https://www.delock.com/produkt/84819/merkmale.html)

SSD:
[Intel® SSD DC P4510 Series](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/122579/intel-ssd-dc-p4510-series-4-0tb-2-5in-pcie-3-1-x4-3d2-tlc.html)

Intel VROC Hardware key: VROCPREMMOD

---

#### Interaction

I access BIOS using the BMC remote control. So the only things plugged to the mainboard are

- USB Keyboard
- Ethernet cable
- Power supply unit

---

#### Versions

I've update BIOS to the latest Version 3601 (2019/02/01)
I've update BMC firmware to the latest Version Version 1.12.3 (2018/10/12)
After that I've performed a CMOS RTC RAM reset.

---

#### BIOS

I've enforced the Compatibility Support Module to always use UEFI.
I've also enabled the (undocumented) X4 U.2 port VROC (in the menu Advanced->CPU Storage Configuration)

[BIOS Settings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCLfh.png)

---

#### What Asus and Intel support says:

- Asus: Return the mainboard again (I've done this)
- Intel: Check NVMe drivers (I've done this)
- Intel: Maybe the mainboard has a "SATA/PCI Switch" - set it to SATA (ASUS: such a switch does not exist)

---

#### Update

I don't think that it's a hardware issue as I have tried:

- Mainboards: 3
- SSDs: 4
- CPUs: 2
- Cables: 4
- RAM: 4

What else could it be?

Comment: You have two options here as I see it: 1) The drive is faulty, does the drive work in another machine? If not replace the drive. 2) The mobo is faulty, return it to Asus.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

I've 2 SSDs - both won't get recognized - coincidance?
I've replaced the board already, so two mainboards seem to have the same issue - also coincidance?

Which way would you go 1) or 2) ?

Comment: Try the drives in a totally different computer, also try swapping out the SATA cable (just to be safe). If the drives work on the other machine you know that the fault lies with the mobo and you should consider buying a different motherboard.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to replace all the parts step by step and will keep the question updated.

Comment: @Burgi Hi, I've replaced RAM, mainboard and the SSDs - still no luck. Maybe both cables are broken..

Comment: @Burgi it doesn't work with different cables - I guess it's a wrong BIOS configuration - what could it be?

Comment: Does the P4510 show up in the BIOS? I have the same m/b and a 4510 drive connected in the same manner and it shows up and is seen by Windows 10 and Linux OS just fine. I am not using that singular drive on my VROC array though.

Comment: @Justin thanks, the drives were broken. Now everything works as expected.

Comment: If you have other questions about this motherboard, happy to help. It's a relatively obscure board for many people, so there isn't a lot of information out there. I'd be happy to pool what scant knowledge I have. If you search reddit for my user name, you will find a post with my workstation configuration posted as a comment.